# Creating a GeoPandas dataframe from GeoDjango query, then extracting latitude values for Plotly

Tags: coordinates, geopandas, geodjango, geodataframe, plotly

I am attempting to use information from my PostGis database with my Django application to make a 3d scatter in Plotly.  I have timeseries data in my database with different metrics from vehicles, and I can create a django pandas dataframe, but it says that `"convert_dtype parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version."` Upon research, I found that this is most likely due to my `gps` column, which contains GeoDjango Point types with latitude and longitude values.  This is the only column in my database which contains any geographic information.

So then, when I attempted to make a GeoPandas dataframe instead, I got another error about valid geometry objects which I will paste below.  I may be trying to make the GeoPandas dataframe wrong. I don't know if I should be putting geometry in since my data are coordinates, but I don't know an alternative.  So any help in correcting the way I am making the dataframe would be appreciated.  From the traceback output, the types and values look correct to me, so I don't think it is an issue of data.

Then, after I manage to create the dataframe with your help, what is the correct way to access latitude and longitude individually from this dataframe?  I will paste what I have tried below.  If there is an easier way to make a 3d scatter plot in Plotly using Point objects, that feedback is appreciated as well.  I have to use Plotly and cannot use another graphing library.  I would like to have latitude as the x value, longitude as the z value, and y as a variable metric (ie. "energy").

Here is my code:

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django_pandas.io import read_frame
from portal.models import Vehicle, VehicleData

# This is not my complete code, just the lines causing issue
if isinstance(VehicleData.objects.all(), QuerySet):
    qs = VehicleData.objects.all()

    # I get the error about deprecated convert_dtype parameter from this line
    dp = read_frame(qs)

    # This is the line that generates the traceback
    gp = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(dp, geometry=dp["gps"], crs="EPSG:4326")

    # This is incomplete and will contain some filtering from a dropdown selection in Plotly Dash so as to only display data for one vehicle on one day. Before moving to GeoPandas, I tried accessing the latitude values by `df["gps"].x` with a result of an error that it has no attribute of "x".  Attempt of `df["gps"][0]` was also unsuccessful.
    fig = px.scatter_3d(gp, x=gp["gps"].x, z=gp["gps"].y, y=gp["energy"], color=gp["energy"])
```

Here is the traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site- 
      packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 192, in __init__
        self.set_geometry(geometry, inplace=True, crs=crs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site- 
      packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 349, in set_geometry
      level = _ensure_geometry(level, crs=crs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site- 
      packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 57, in _ensure_geometry
      out = from_shapely(np.asarray(data), crs=crs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/geopandas/array.py", 
      line 159, in from_shapely
      return GeometryArray(vectorized.from_shapely(data), crs=crs)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site- 
      packages/geopandas/_vectorized.py", line 146, in from_shapely
      raise TypeError("Input must be valid geometry objects: 
      {0}".format(geom))
      TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: SRID=4326;POINT 
      (52.093448638916016 5.117378234863281)
```

Edit:
Here is some additional output from my django shell:

```
    >>> print(dp["gps"][0])
    SRID=4326;POINT (52.093448638916016 5.117378234863281)
    >>> print(dp["gps"][0][0])
    52.093448638916016
    >>> gps[0].x
    52.093448638916016
```

So I am able to access individual rows' latitude values just using django pandas.  Is there a reason for me to use GeoPandas instead?  Is there a way to reference a whole column's latitude values, or would I have to put my figure in a loop?

```
qlen = qs.count()
for i in range(0, qlen, 1):
    fig = px.scatter_3d(dp, x=gps[i].x, y=dp["energy"], z=gps[i].y)
```

Comment: This doesn't have to be complex. Your error indicates getting *extended* Well-Known Text (EWKT) not Well-Known Text (WKT), which can be resolved by splitting off the "SRID={int};" from the front of the string.

Comment: @Vince: How would I spit off the "SRID=4326"?  I have tried `gp = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(dp, geometry=dp["gps"].split(";")[1], crs="EPSG:4326")`  and get an error. "AttrbuteError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'. Did you mean 'plot'?"

Comment: You seem to be using an implicit stringify, so an explicit `str()` might suffice.